# Unable to login to remote server using ssh

Tags: server

I am not able to login to the remote server. Some times it allowed to connect and some times it simply denied the permission.
I tried to restart the ssh service on the remote server using `sudo systemctl restart sshd.service`, but the problem remains unsolved.

I have checked the status using `service ssh status` and the server is in the "Active" state.

Comment: Did you make sure that openssh-server is installed on your remote server?

Comment: Have you tried `-v` (ie. verbose mode) to look for clues?

Comment: Yes. I am using this server since last few months and everything was perfectly fine. But, suddenly it start giving the problem.

Comment: Yes. I tried -v mode , but the problem remains unsolved. It gives message like "debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.